# performSelectorinBackground in certain time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS programming and I made a little game.

I have some sprites in the background of my scene which I want to move slowly from left to right.
Right now I'm doing this in the MainScene:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doBackgroundAnimation:) withObject:sprite];
```

and the method in which the animation takes place looks like this:

```
-(void)doBackgroundAnimation:(CCNode *)sprite {
while (//sprite is still in the scene) {
//move sprite a little bit right
        }
}
```

This solution is not really what I was looking for, since the time it takes to run through the while-loop varies from device to device.

Is there a way to make sure that the animation takes an exact amount of time e.g. 5 seconds?
Something like:

```
performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doBackgroundAnimation:) withObject:turtle inTime:5.0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For animations, use the animation frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did game stuff but you have to adjust the distance you move the sprite according to the time since the last update of the screen. So you have a var called speed that you * by the time since the last refresh and then move the sprite that distance.

There are methods in sprite kit that deal with this. There are lots of tutorials on YouTube that cover this.